# Pipe error while executing multiple commands using pipe in custom shell

Tags: c, shell, pipe

I am trying to execute multiple commands in my customised shell using pipe. While the code doesn't show any error, the terminal just hangs there without any output. My code snippet is as follows :

```
void exe_pipe(char *pipe1[])
{
    int pipe_end[2*l], n=0;

    for( i = 0; i < l; i++ ) {
        pipe ( pipe_end + i*2 );
    }

    for( m = 0; m < (l+1); m++ ) // l is no. of pipes
    {
        pid = fork();
        if( pid == 0 )
        {           
            if ( m > 0 )
                dup2( pipe_end[ (n-1)*2] , 0 );             
            if ( m < (l+1) )
                dup2( pipe_end[ (n*2)+1] , 1 );  

            execlp( pipe1[m], pipe1[m], (char*)NULL );

        }       
    }

    for( i = 0; i < 2 * l; i++ )
    {
        close( pipe_end[i] );
    }

    while(waitpid(-1, NULL, 0) != -1);  
}
```

Ok I think I got it. My edits :

```
for( m = 0; m < l+1; m++ )
{
    pid = fork();
    if( pid == 0 )
    {

        if ( m > 0 )
        {
            dup2( pipe_end[ (m-1)*2 ] , 0 );  
        }

        if ( m < (l+1) )
        {
            dup2( pipe_end[ (m*2)+1 ] , 1 );    
        }
        for(i = 0; i < 2 * l; i++){
                close(pipe_end[i]);}    
        execlp( pipe1[m], pipe1[m], (char*)NULL );

    }

}
```

Comment: Won't `for( m = 0; m <= (l+1); m++)` loop one time too many?  And don't you need to actually create the pipes?

Comment: l+1 is my number of commands since l is the no. of pipes. Ya i created them in my prog. Missed it while posting it here. Edited now

Comment: ..but `for( m = 0; m <= (l+1); m++)` loops `l + 2` times (`0` to `l+1`)

Comment: Oh yes. Thanks. But no change in my output yet.

Comment: Don't forget to change `if ( m < (l+1) )` to `if ( m < l )` to match..

Comment: In the first "pipe" call "i" is not defined. Pipe should be called in a loop, same as close. The dup2 calls use a negative index. There are so many problems with this, it probably wont even compile.

Comment: But I need to loop my 'no. of commands' times right?  @davlet : i defined it earlier(its a long code) and i piped using loop itself. Sorry for the wrong typo. Changed it now. I get the feeling my problem is with dup2 but don't know what

Comment: ...and it compiles just fine. After I enter commands the shell just hangs there doing nothing.

Comment: pipe_end[ (n-1)*2] -- is the same as pipe_end[-2] because n is always 0; the next dup2 's index is also off

Comment: Why are you creating pipes if you are not reading or writing them in the parent? Its pointless.

Comment: In your `dup2()`s, `n` should be `m`.  Also, you'll need to close all the unused pipe ends in each child process (or at least the write ends) or the commands won't see EOF when the preceeding command finishes.

Comment: I understood. Thanks. I got my code working